# Object from controller to view

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm new with PHP and the MVC pattern. I try to do an app which display images. Here is what I've done in my controller :

```
protected function setImg() {
    global $id, $size;  
    $imgDAO = new ImageDAO();

        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $imgId = $_GET["id"];
            $img = $imgDAO->getImage($imgId);
            var_dump($img);
        } else {
            $img = $imgDAO->getFirstImage();
            $imgId = $img->getId();
        }
        if (isset($_GET["size"])) {
            $size = $_GET["size"];
        } else {
        $size = 480;
    }
}

function viewPhoto() {
            global $id, $size;
            $this->getParam();
            $this->setImg();
            require_once("view/viewPhoto.php");
}
```

And in my view, I try to display the image thanks to the path :

```
<?php $imgURL = $img->getURL();
            print "<img src=\"$imgURL\" width=\"$size\">\n";
            ?>
```

But `$img` is undefined. Something is missing in my controller but I don't know what

Comment: None of the code you've pasted has anything that passes anything to... anything, except those crazy globals.

Comment: @rjdown So what should I do ?

Comment: At the very least, you need your setImg method to do something. Either return $img, or set a property on the class that can later be retrieved.

Comment: i would avoid using global

Answer (score 0):

it should be `$this->img = $imgDAO->getImage($imgId);` 
`$this->img = $imgDAO->getFirstImage();` // not $img = ...

as far as I now

```
//  bootstrap

$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);

//Controller.php

function __construct($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->view = new View($model);
}

// This way the controller would call

$this->view->show_picture($this->img->getURL());

// View

function __construct($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
}

function show_picture($imgUrl) {
    print "<img src=\"$imgURL\" width=\"$size\">\n";
}
```